# Mac terminal installer: Error trying to locate volume at /Applications

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to install a pkg from the terminal. It works as

`sudo installer -pkg desktop/test/firefox.pkg -target /`

but this sends it to the root folder and I need it to go to the Applications folder.

Answer (score 3):

When the command used is: "installer -package path/to/package -target / " it installs the package into /Applications by default.

Answer (score 0):

You set `-target` to the root folder by putting a `/` after it. Instead, put the path to your applications folder. Your new command should look like this:

```
sudo installer -pkg desktop/test/firefox.pkg -target /path/to/Applications
```

Comment: Still getting this error installer: Error trying to locate volume at /path/to/Applications

Comment: @KristinCanterbury did you replace /path/to/Applications with the actual path to your Applications folder?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be /"volume name"/applications or /applications because it's in the root folder? I've tried both ways with the same error

Comment: Try pressing tab twice after typing the /slash. You should be given a list of subfolders

Comment: It does and it lists the Applications/ folder but still same error. installer: Error trying to locate volume at /Applications/

Comment: What error are you getting, and please post the updated command you ran along with it